# How to retrieve address in custom html form and send to paypal?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, paypal

So i have written an html order form with 5 fields(company name, firstname, lastname, email and address.) http://www.topchoicedata.com/175.php#175

When the user clicks submit, it will take them to a paypal payment page. I used a cool script called paypal payment form from hotdreamweaver script, which converts any form into a paypal form. This creates the action called "PPPaymentForm/PPPaymentForm.php" PHP can be found under this link  http://www.cedarpublishing.com/phpcode.txt

The problem i am having is that paypal is not able to retrieve the address and when the person buys the product from me, it says from the buyer end(me) that no shipping address was provided and that i have to confirm with the buyer. So i need a way so that paypal grabs that address field when they submit the order form, and even the first and last names if possible.

I read up on paypal variables, but i am unsure on how to embed them. Below is my form.

```
<form action="PPPaymentForm/PPPaymentForm.php"  method="post" name="topchoiceform" id="topchoiceform">
    <input placeholder="Company Name" type="text" name="companyname" required>
    <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="firstname" required>
    <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="lastname" required>
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <input placeholder="Address" type="text" name="address" required>
    <input name="shipping" class="shipping" type="checkbox" id="shipping" value="19.99"/>
    <label class="shippingcheck">19.99(Optional Shipping, will be added to total if chosen)</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Pay Now</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwtablename" id="hdwtablename" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppproductname" id="hdwppproductname" value="Basic Plan $175">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppamount" id="hdwppamount" value="175">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwppcurrency" id="hdwppcurrency" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwpplanguage" id="hdwpplanguage" value="en_US">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwok" id="hdwok" value="http://">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwemail" id="hdwemail" value="mauriceflopez+gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwnook" id="hdwnook" value="http://">
    <input type="hidden" name="hdwactivation_email" id="hdwactivation_email" value="none">
    <input type="hidden" name="plan" id="plan" value="$175">
    <input type="hidden" name="shippingchoosen" id="shippingchoosen" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="shippingnumber" id="shippingnumber" value="">

  </form>
```

Comment: Should not you require a shipping address within your PayPal Account then use IPN to do that?

Comment: I am honestly not to sure, i simply made a html form, and then used the paypal payment form script, which generated the files in PPPaymentForm/PPPaymentForm.php, i uploaded and the transaction works fine, only problem is the custom address field which the person submits does not get picked up by paypal. Any help would be appreciated.